# optimal algorithm grouping data in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, grouping, lodash

The following (simplified) json type of data defines a Contact:

```
{
  id:   number;
  name: string;
  phone: string;
  email: string
}
```

There is the following group of data:

```
+---+----------+-------------+---------------------------+ 
|id | name     | phone       |email                      | 
+---+----------+-------------+---------------------------+
|1  | John     | 11111111    |aaaa@test.com              | 
|2  | Marc     | 22222222    |bbbb@test.com              | 
|3  | Ron      | 99999999    |aaaa@test.com              |
|4  | Andrew   | 55555555    |dddd@test.com              |
|5  | Wim      | 99999999    |gggg@test.com              |
|6  | Marc     | 33333333    |cccc@test.com              |
|7  | Dan      | 44444444    |cccc@test.com              |
+---+----------+-------------+---------------------------+
```

Goal is to find the groups that belong together using javascript(optionally in lodash, but main idea is to get the algorithm clear) according to the following constraint: a contact belongs to a group when any of the following criteria are the same: name, phone or email. The results shows the id's grouped as arrays in arrays. a contact in a group of 1 is ignored.

In the example above, it means that contacts with ids 1,3,5 belong together since 1,3 share the same email and 3 and 5 share the same phonenumber. Likewise 2,6,7: 2 and 6 have the same name and 6 and 7 have the same email. 5 does not have anything in common.
The expected result therefore is:
`[[1,3,5], [2,6,7]]`

Background:
One solution that works is iterating over every item and check for the remainder of the list if name, email, or phone is the same. If so, group them and take them out of the list (in the example we compare 1 with all the items in the list and only 3 is found). problem is that next items also need to be checked again to these groups, because in this case 5 is not yet detected as part of the group. This makes the algorithm complex, while I suspect there is a simple way of solving this in linear time. There might also be a name for this class of problems?
`

Comment: That looks like a cool problem... Just to make sure that I understood it correctly: what would it be the expected result if #2 had the following phone #: `99999999`? Would it be `[[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]]`?

Comment: correct, we would have one group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea:

- Start with 0 groups
- Iterate your list of contacts
- Check if there is a group with the contact name, or phone, or email. Merge all the members of those groups as the same group. Then add yourself to that group. If not, begin a new group with yourself and set the name, phone and email group as yourself.

Union find is an efficient structure to handle merging of [disjoint sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Code taken from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mikkanu/287x2/). As it uses path compression and union by rank, you can consider that the whole code is linear in the amount of contacts.

```js
var data = [
      {id:1,name:'John',phone:'11111111',email:'aaaa@test.com'},
      {id:2,name:'Marc',phone:'99999999',email:'bbbb@test.com'},
      {id:3,name:'Ron',phone:'99999999',email:'aaaa@test.com'},
      {id:4,name:'Andrew',phone:'55555555',email:'dddd@test.com'},
      {id:5,name:'Wim',phone:'99999999',email:'gggg@test.com'},
      {id:6,name:'Marc',phone:'33333333',email:'cccc@test.com'},
      {id:7,name:'Dan',phone:'44444444',email:'cccc@test.com'}
];

// UNION-FIND structure, with path comression and union by rank

var UNIONFIND = (function () {
    
    function _find(n)
    {
        if(n.parent == n) return n; 
        n.parent = _find(n.parent); 
        return n.parent;
    }
    
    return {
        makeset:function(id){    
            var newnode = {
                parent: null,
                id: id,
                rank: 0
            };
            newnode.parent = newnode;            
            return newnode;
        },
    
        find: _find,
     
        combine: function(n1, n2) {                                    
            var n1 = _find(n1);
            var n2 = _find(n2);
            
            if (n1 == n2) return;
        
            if(n1.rank < n2.rank)
            {
                n2.parent = n2;
                return n2;
            }
            else if(n2.rank < n1.rank)
            {
                n2.parent = n1;
                return n1;
            }
            else
            {
                n2.parent = n1;
                n1.rank += 1;
                return n1;
            }
        }
    };
})();

var groupHash = {name: {}, phone: {}, email: {}}
var groupNodes = []

data.forEach(function(contact){
  var group = UNIONFIND.makeset(contact.id);
  var groups = new Set();
  ["name", "phone", "email"].forEach(function(attr){
    if (groupHash[attr].hasOwnProperty(contact[attr])) groups.add(groupHash[attr][contact[attr]])
  });
  
  groups = Array.from(groups);
  groups.push(group);
  groupNodes.push(group);
  
  for(var i = 1; i < groups.length; i++) {
    UNIONFIND.combine(groups[0], groups[i]);
  }  
  
  ["name", "phone", "email"].forEach(function(attr){
      groupHash[attr][contact[attr]] = groups[0];
  });
  
})

var contactsInGroup = {}


groupNodes.forEach(function(group){
    var groupId = UNIONFIND.find(group).id;
    
    if (contactsInGroup.hasOwnProperty(groupId) == false) {
      contactsInGroup[groupId] = [];
    }
    
    contactsInGroup[groupId].push(group.id);
})

var result = Object.values(contactsInGroup).filter(function(list){
 return list.length > 1
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Using `Map` instead of JS objects would allow you to avoid `hasOwnProperty`. You already use `Set`, which has a similar API and advantages.

Comment: Your code seems to do mostly the same as mine, but you merge your groups on-the-fly while I wait until all are built to start processing merges. Both should be linear in the number of entries.

Comment: @tucuxi I usually only use map for object references, but it could be used yeah. Nice solution that doesn´t need an extra structure like union find. Tested with data replicated until 450k entries and yours takes 850ms while mine 1050ms, definitely both linear ^^

Answer (score 2):

Any answer that iterates over each of `n` entries, and then over a growing list of `m` groups to match against is going to have worst-time performance of `O(n*m)` (found when there are no two entries that match on any term).

Any answer that iterates over each entry, and then over groups, and uses arrays to test for matching values among `q` options will further have to pay a penalty of `O(q)` per match. In the worst case, with say all e-mails the same and all phones different, this will mean `O(n*m)`.

I believe this answer is `O(n)`, because assuming that the number of fields to match with is a constant (in this case, 3: `name`, `phone` and `email`), all operations in the main loop, which is run once per entry, are `O(1)`.

There is an extra complication to fix the fact that, late in the process, we may find a bridge between two (or even 3) groups, as entries can match on different fields with entries from different groups. This may happen several times. To avoid having to rebuild groups during the main loop, we leave merging to the very end, where we first build a map of what-group-ends-up-where, and then finally move all entry IDs to their final group. This can all be done in `O(m)`, with m the number of groups; with an extra `O(n)` when actually copying entry IDs to the merged groups: overall, we are still in `O(n)` territory.

The last line builds arrays of ids from the merged groups, and filters out any that does not have over 1 element.

```
const data = [
    {id:1,name:'John',phone:'11111111',email:'aaaa@test.com'},
    {id:2,name:'Marc',phone:'99999999',email:'bbbb@test.com'},
    {id:3,name:'Ron',phone:'99999999',email:'aaaa@test.com'},
    {id:4,name:'Andrew',phone:'55555555',email:'dddd@test.com'},
    {id:5,name:'Wim',phone:'99999999',email:'gggg@test.com'},
    {id:6,name:'Marc',phone:'33333333',email:'cccc@test.com'},
    {id:7,name:'Dan',phone:'44444444',email:'cccc@test.com'}
];

const groups = function(inputs) {

    let valuesToGroups = new Map(
        ['name', 'phone', 'email'].map(key => [key, new Map()]));
    let groups = new Map();
    let pendingMerges = [];
    for (const entry of inputs) {
        let group = undefined;
        let found = [];
        for (const [key, valueMap] of valuesToGroups) {
            // look up value in values-index for current key
            group = valueMap.get(entry[key]);
            if (group !== undefined) {
                found.push(group);
                // not breaking allows groups to be merged
            }
        }
        if (found.length === 0) {
            // not found: create new group
            group = groups.size;
            groups.set(group, [entry.id]);
        } else {
            // found: add entry to chosen group
            group = found[0];
            groups.get(group).push(entry.id);
            if (found.length > 1) {
                pendingMerges.push(found);
            }
        }
        // add entry's values to index, pointing to group
        for (const [key, valueMap] of valuesToGroups) {
            valueMap.set(entry[key], group); 
        }        
    }
    // do pending merges; initially, all groups are stand-alone
    let merges = new Map(Array.from(groups.keys()).map(k => [k, k]));
    for (const merge of pendingMerges) {
        // contents will go to the lowest-numbered group
        const sorted = merge.map(groupId => merges.get(groupId)).sort();
        sorted.forEach(groupId => merges.set(groupId, sorted[0]));
    }
    const cleanGroups = new Map();
    groups.forEach((value, key) => { 
        const k = merges.get(key); 
        if ( ! cleanGroups.has(k)) {
            cleanGroups.set(k, []);
        }
        value.forEach(id => cleanGroups.get(k).push(id))
    })
    // return only non-empty groups
    return [... cleanGroups].filter(g => g[1].length>1).map(g => [... g[1]]);
}(data);

console.log(""+JSON.stringify(groups))
// output is [[1,2,3,5,6,7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another suggestion of a route you could take. The idea is to use one [**`Array.reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group by `id` and keep all the values (`vls`) and combined results (`ids`) in that `accumulator object`.

This way you can easily compare the `name/phone/email` using [**`Array.some`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) + [**`Array.includes`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (which is what the `getGroupId` function does).

Once you have grouped and have the almost final result just `prettify` it by removing the groups with `length` of one and picking only the `ids` array of the rest:

```js
var data = [ {id:1,name:'John',phone:'11111111',email:'aaaa@test.com'}, {id:2,name:'Marc',phone:'22222222',email:'bbbb@test.com'}, {id:3,name:'Ron',phone:'99999999',email:'aaaa@test.com'}, {id:4,name:'Andrew',phone:'55555555',email:'dddd@test.com'}, {id:5,name:'Wim',phone:'99999999',email:'gggg@test.com'}, {id:6,name:'Marc',phone:'33333333',email:'cccc@test.com'}, {id:7,name:'Dan',phone:'44444444',email:'cccc@test.com'} ];

const getGroupId = (obj, vals) => Object.entries(obj)
   .find(([k,v]) => v.vls.some(x => vals.includes(x))) || []

const group = d => d.reduce((r, c) => {
   let values = Object.values(c), groupID = getGroupId(r, values)[0]
 
   if(!groupID) 
      r[c.id] = ({ vls: values, ids: [...r[c.id] || [], c.id] })
   else {
      r[groupID] = ({
         vls: [...r[groupID].vls, ...values], ids: [...r[groupID].ids, c.id]
      })
   }
   return r
}, {})

const prettify = grp => Object.values(grp).reduce((r,c) => {
   if(c.ids.length > 1)
     r.push(c.ids)
     return r
}, [])

console.log(prettify(group(data)))
```

One thing to note is that we do not care about the number of properties since we do `Object.values`. So you can easily add another `address` or `fax` to that list and it would still work with `zero code changes`.

As per feedback here is another version which works slightly different:

```js
var data = [ {id:1,name:'John',phone:'11111111',email:'aaaa@test.com'}, {id:2,name:'Marc',phone:'22222222',email:'bbbb@test.com'}, {id:3,name:'Ron',phone:'99999999',email:'aaaa@test.com'}, {id:4,name:'Andrew',phone:'55555555',email:'dddd@test.com'}, {id:5,name:'Wim',phone:'99999999',email:'gggg@test.com'}, {id:6,name:'Marc',phone:'33333333',email:'cccc@test.com'}, {id:7,name:'Dan',phone:'44444444',email:'cccc@test.com'} ];
var testData = [{ id: 1, name: 'John', phone: '1', email: 'a' }, { id: 2, name: 'Marc', phone: '2', email: 'b' }, { id: 3, name: 'Ron', phone: '1', email: 'b' }]; 

const getGroupId = (obj, vals) => Object.entries(obj)
  .find(([k,v]) => v.vls.some(x => vals.includes(x))) || []

const group = d => d.reduce((r,c,i,a) => {
  let values = Object.values(c), groupID = !i ? i : getGroupId(r, values)[0]

  if (!groupID) {  
    let hits = a.filter(x => 
       x.id != c.id && values.some(v => Object.values(x).includes(v)))
    hits.forEach(h => 
       r[c.id] = ({ vls: [...values, ...Object.values(h)], ids: [c.id, h.id] }))
  }
  else
    r[groupID] = r[groupID].ids.includes(c.id) ? r[groupID] : 
      ({ vls: [...r[groupID].vls, ...values], ids: [...r[groupID].ids, c.id] })      
  return r
}, {})

const prettify = grp => Object.values(grp).reduce((r, c) => {
  if (c.ids.length > 1)
    r.push(c.ids)
  return r
}, [])

console.log(prettify(group(data)))      // OP data
console.log(prettify(group(testData)))  // Test data
```

The reason for this version is due to the `testData` provided by `@Mark` which has the 2nd element not matching the first but matching the 3rd which actually matches the 1st ... so they all should be hits.

To get to that once we find a match we look for matches of that same initial match and push in the same group so we can have the maximum amount of data to match on.

The result is that once we get the first group with the first element we then find and push the 3rd as well and from there it is much easier to match the 2nd. The logic is slightly more complex and I would imagine less performant.

Comment: I would expect these to all be in one group: `{id:1,name:'John',phone:'1',email:'a'}, {id:2,name:'Marc',phone:'2',email:'b'}{id:3,name:'Ron', phone:'1',email:'b'}`, but it seems to leave 2 out.

Comment: I did not get it the first time due to the funky formatting in the comments section but you ware correct. I updated with another version which matches as expected. Thanks.

Comment: The matching code seems to iterate over all values. This is wasteful, because a map could, on the right field, report on matches in `O(1)`. Your code is brief (I have not looked into its correctness), but cannot be optimal.

Comment: In order to get the correctness of the groupings you have to scan for matches once you got the initial hit. I am not saying it is perfect but it is pretty generic and could be optimized more for sure.

Answer (score -1):

One way to accomplish what you need, is to separate the contacts into groups.
Each group will contain a list of `names`, `phones` and `emails`.

Then iterate through contacts, and see if the current contact falls into any of the groups. If not, create a new group and set its `names/phones/emails` so that next contacts might fall into the same on.

```js
var data = [
      {id:1,name:'John',phone:'11111111',email:'aaaa@test.com'},
      {id:2,name:'Marc',phone:'22222222',email:'bbbb@test.com'},
      {id:3,name:'Ron',phone:'99999999',email:'aaaa@test.com'},
      {id:4,name:'Andrew',phone:'55555555',email:'dddd@test.com'},
      {id:5,name:'Wim',phone:'99999999',email:'gggg@test.com'},
      {id:6,name:'Marc',phone:'33333333',email:'cccc@test.com'},
      {id:7,name:'Dan',phone:'44444444',email:'cccc@test.com'}
];

var groups = [];

data.forEach(function(person){
  var phone = person.phone;
  var email = person.email;
  var name = person.name;
  var id = person.id;
  var found = false;
  groups.forEach(function(g){
    if(    g.names.indexOf(name) > -1 
        || g.phones.indexOf(phone)>-1 
        || g.emails.indexOf(email)>-1) {
      found = true;
      g.names.push(name);
      g.phones.push(phone);
      g.emails.push(email);
      g.people.push(id);
    }
  });
  if(!found) {
      groups.push({names:[name],phones:[phone],emails:[email],people:[id]});
  }
  
  
});
var output=[];
groups.forEach(function(g){
  output.push(g.people);
});
console.log(output);   //[ [1,3,5] , [2,6,7] , [4] ]
```

Comment: O(n^2*log(n)) ? I thought OP was looking for an optimal solution

Comment: the log(n) part is ok, but the multiplication with quadratic part n^2 will cause problems for bigger datasets. However, do not have better solution myself

Comment: Groups with only 1 element should not be part of the result as per OP. `[4]` should not be in the result.